# Some Unicode characters do not show up correctly anywhere in the system ಠ_ಠ

Tags: encoding, unicode, character-set

ಠ_ಠ looks like squares in Google Chrome and in Sublime Text Editor.

16.10 (Yakkety Yak)

seems like I have to reconfigure or reinstall some package...

Comment: I think it is a problem with Unicode support in those applications. May be font related.